# MPLAB 8: Hotkey for "Program Target Device"

Tags: pic, programming, microchip, mplab, pickit

I am looking for a hotkey that will have the same effect as "Program Target Device" from the toolbar or menu.

```
Programming Target (4/7/2012  7:55:43 AM)
PIC24F16KA101 found (Rev 0x8)
Erasing Target
Programming Program Memory (0x0 - 0x143F)
Verifying Program Memory (0x0 - 0x143F)
Programming Configuration Memory
Verifying Configuration Memory
PICkit 2 Ready
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a hotkey assigned to that action by default. However, you can define your own hotkey:

MPLAB -> Configure -> Settings... -> Hot Keys -> Command -> PICkit 2 Programmer.Program

Answer (score 2):

I don't have MPLAB open right now, but you can use keys for most things.  Maybe there isn't a single hot key for DEBUG > PROGRAM, but Alt-D G (or whatever the key for "program" is) should do it.  You might be able to assign your own hot key, but I haven't played with that recently.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the cli version of the programmer PK2CMD.